# Loading multiple Fullcalendars in jquery tabs fails - loads all in 1st tab

Tags: jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I am attempting to do two things:

1. Create multiple instances of a Fullcalendar displaying different event sources - this seems to be working when stacked on a page.
2. I need each Fullcalendar instance to appear within a different jquery tab.  I have the tabbing code correct and working but for some reason all calendars are loaded within the 1st tab even though I am specifying each Fullcalendar to be on separate tab.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using something similar to the code below. Works fine with jquery ui tabs. I'm using JSON for my event sources but you can add whatever event source you need etc.

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
  show: function() {
    $('#calendar1').fullCalendar('render');
    $('#calendar2').fullCalendar('render');
  }
});

$('#calendar1').fullCalendar({
  eventSources: [
    "json_events1.php"
  ]
});

$('#calendar2').fullCalendar({
  eventSources: [
    "json_events2.php"
  ]
});
```